# There seems to be a mismatch between last deployed API and actually in-use API

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, swagger-2.0, openapi

According to Google Cloud Console > Endpoints > Services > Deployment History this is the currently deployed API spec:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  title: "JSON Ingester"
  description: "Receive JSON files, transform and load them."
  version: "1.0.0"

host: "project-id-123.appspot.com"
schemes:
  - "https"

paths:
  "/upload":
    post:
      summary: "ETL JSON file."
      security:
        - api_key: []
      operationId: "upload"
      consumes:
        - multipart/form-data
      parameters:
        - in: formData
          name: file
          type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: "File uploaded."
          schema:
            type: string
        400:
          description: "Error during file upload."

securityDefinitions:
  api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "apikey"
    in: "query"
```

But the key "apikey" is not accepted - instead it requires "key" which was specified in an openapi.yaml that I deployed few hours ago.

This works while it shouldn't:

```
$ curl -X POST -F "file=@data/file_6.json" https://project-id-123.appspot.com/upload\?key\=AIzaS...Eaoog
```

And this doesn't work while it should:

```
$ curl -X POST -F "file=@data/file_6.json" https://project-id-123.appspot.com/upload\?apikey\=AIzaS...Eaoog
{
 "code": 16,
 "message": "Method doesn't allow unregistered callers (callers without established identity). Please use API Key or other form of API consumer identity to call this API.",
 "details": [
  {
   "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
   "stackEntries": [],
   "detail": "service_control"
  }
 ]
}
```

Do I have to clear a cache or something?

For deploying the API I use:

```
gcloud endpoints services deploy "./openapi.yaml"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What [rollout_strategy](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp/blob/master/start_esp/start_esp.py#L567) did you use when you deploy ESP?  If not specified, default is "fixed".  You should use "managed"

Please also check the generated service config by CLI "gcloud endpoints configs describe".  Check its system_parameters filed to see if your new "apikey" is created properly.